# Searching if values exist

Tags: ruby

My application needs to read data from a file and then the user can search for that data to see if it exists. The file reads the ID of an album, then the user must enter that ID in order to access it

The text file

```
Marcus Hospin
Raw
3 - Genre Value
1 - ID 
Sag My Pants
sounds/01-Sag-My-Pants.wav
The Purge
sounds/06-The-Purge.wav
Ill Mind 8
sounds/20-Ill-Mind-8.wav
```

The ruby code

```
class Album
  attr_accessor :title, :artist, :genre, :id, :tracks

  def initialize (title, artist, genre, id)
    @title = title
    @artist = artist
    @genre = genre
    @id = id

  end
end

def read_album(music_file)
  album_artist = music_file.gets
  album_title = music_file.gets
  album_genre = music_file.gets
  album_id = music_file.gets
  album = Album.new(album_title, album_artist, album_genre, album_id)
  album
end

def main
album = read_album(music_file)
puts 'Enter the ID of the album you wish to play'
      search_string = gets.to_s
      album.map(&:id).include?(search_string) || -1
      if index != -1
        puts "Found, playing album " + album[index].id + " at " + index.to_s
      else
        puts "Entry not Found"
      end
end

main
```

The expected result is for the program to return, "Found, playing album 1(ID) at 1(index). But the actual ouput is `` undefined method `map' for #<Album:0x0000000003357ca0> (NoMethodError) ``

Comment: Your code looks like the one in https://stackoverflow.com/q/56000459/477037 – is this a duplicate or a follow-up question? Are you both trying to solve the same assignment or something?

Comment: @Stefan: This is actually at least the tenth almost identical question with almost identical code having almost identical errors. I cannot tell if this is the same person asking the same question over and over again and refusing to learn from the answers, or different persons asking the same question over and over again, refusing to use search engines. They always have useless titles, they always have made no attempt to reduce the code to a [mcve], and they mostly don't respond to questions for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is undefined because you call it on a single object, instead of a collection of objects. You need to fill an array with `Album` objects, before you can `map` over it.